# CartoDB create layer at runtime

Tags: carto, api, visualisation

I'm almost totally new to CartoDB. I've been looking around and read the api reference, but there seems not to be what I'm looking for.

What I want to do is to "Create visualizations at runtime". From what I read, it is possible to do it only if you already have a visualization created with the UI and then you can work with sublayers.

But what I actually want to do is to create a visualization from scratch, using just the table containing the values I want to represent on the map.

Is this possible or I'm totally out of mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, totally possible. That is what this portion is about [Visualization at runtime](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#runtime)

You'll see that the method doesn't include anything about an existing visualization, but just defines sublayers for a new one on the fly. The sublayers contain info about the table and columns you wish to use. Here it is generically,

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: 'your user name',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    sql: "SELECT * FROM table_name",
    cartocss: '#table_name {marker-fill: #F0F0F0;}'
  }]
})
.addTo(map)
```

Where `table_name` is just that, the table you want to turn into a visualization. Your username can be found by the URL of your account, it is always `http://username.cartodb.com...` when you are signed in.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Actually that's what i'm trying to do, but i always receive a 404.. no idea on how to debug it... Any clue?

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps your table is private? If you are on a free account, this shouldn't be the case. Are you using chrome? Could you drop a link to one of your failed tile requests?

Comment: I'm using a free account, and yes using chrome. is that a problem? trying with ff, in console i get no errors... this should be the link you asked https://sissy0584.cartodb.com/tables/output_new/

Comment: i tried with a different table and that seems to work... really strange behaviour. Thanks for your help indeed :) i had a moment of total panic :)

Comment: anyway you can create a public gist (gist.github.com) of your code?

Comment: thanks for your attention. This is the gist with the interesting code: https://gist.github.com/sissy0584/9355861 right now also the first table seems to work. Anyway i'm finding lots of trouble customizing the view and just discovered it's not possible to use infowindows with such a layer... i'm quite disappointed by this.

Comment: Sorry, can you put the relevant code including the real table names etc?

Comment: and username...

Comment: the table name is the real one (i'm still prototyping). just added my real username. hope it helps :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13381/discussion-between-sissy-and-andrewxhill)

Comment: finally, here is a working example from javisantana https://gist.github.com/javisantana/49d31ea2787a53e7ae2d

Comment: Thank you very much @andrewxhill, this is working fine. By the way i couldn't find this methods in the api documentation, no mentions about creating a visualization from scratch and working with it. This was just the beginning and i'm a bit worried on trying to get things a bit more complex. Could you please advice me on where can i find such a documentation? For example: is it working the same way with legends? Thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: no problem! yep, our documentation (http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#runtime) is a working progress. Many of the things we have created examples for, (e.g. legends http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/6409970) but haven't gotten them wrapped back into the main documentation. We are in the process of moving it to a new management system so that it is easier to grow. we are also bringing in a couple new people that are going to help make it happen faster!

Comment: i see, the problem is that i need to use it now... heheh well i'll continue to look for examples here and here and posting questions here and in your dedicated google group hoping someone can address me with the right methods. Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: @andrewxhill this is great support thanks. Im doing something similar, but my tables contain mostly polygon data, however when I create the sublayer it shows points not shapes. Anyway to specify what geographic column to use? (I assumed it would take 'the_geom' column by default) Thanks!